# Tinkerpop Gremlin - How to simplify {a - b} maths on a 2 count array?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm trying to do something that should be quite simple. I have a stream of arrays that contain 2 edges. For each array, I just want to subtract a value on the second edge from that of the first. In some languages, this would simply be `array[0].value - array[1].value`. However, I've only managed to achieve this doing the following:

```
local(
    project('a', 'b').
      by(unfold().limit(1)).
      by(unfold().tail(1)).
    math('a - b').
      by('bias'))
```

This works, however it seems this should be much simpler without `project()`, `limit()` and `tail()`. It also makes me question how I would get the correct item from an array if there were 3 or more items in there. Eg. how would I get the second item if it's no longer the `tail()`? I guess `limit(2).tail(1)`? It just seems extremely messy. If I simple use a `fold()` step, I can get extremely close to simplifying this operation:

```
local(
    unfold().
    values('bias').
    fold(0, minus))
```

Using `fold()` in this way is so clean, however results in `0 - a - b`. If I could replace that seed with a dynamic value, then I could achieve more. But even then, I would have to do something like `(2 * a) - a - b`, to achieve the correct result. Attempts to replace the `0` seed with a dynamic variable such as `limit(1).values('bias')` fail as it's the wrong type. But I wouldn't be satisfied with such arbitrary code anyway. Then My final thought was to index the items then select by index:

```
local(
    index().
      with(WithOptions.indexer, WithOptions.map))
```

While the edges are indexed fine, I can't find a way to make this useful. I thought I could `select('0')` to get the first item, but nothing is returned.

I guess my question is as follows:
Is there a simple way to achieve `a - b` as simply as `a + b` is achieved with `sum()` or `fold(0, sum)`?
If not, Is there a cleaner way of choosing items in an array for maths? Or should everything generally be put in `project()` before maths? It just seems so cumbersome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip `project()` easy enough:

```
gremlin> arr = [[g.E(7).next(),g.E(8).next()],[g.E(8).next(),g.E(10).next()]]
==>[e[7][1-knows->2],e[8][1-knows->4]]
==>[e[8][1-knows->4],e[10][4-created->5]]
gremlin> g.inject(arr).unfold().as('a','b').
......1>   math('a - b').
......2>     by(limit(local,1).values('weight')).
......3>     by(tail(local,1).values('weight'))
==>-0.5
==>0.0
```

You still have to `unfold().limit()/tail()` but I'd say this is a better approach as it avoids creating a `Map` just to throw it away.

> It also makes me question how I would get the correct item from an array if there were 3 or more items in there. Eg. how would I get the second item if it's no longer the tail()? I guess limit(2).tail(1)?

You could use `range()` to avoid a multi-step approach:

```
gremlin> arr = [[g.E(7).next(),g.E(8).next(),g.E(9).next()],[g.E(8).next(),g.E(10).next(),g.E(10).next()]]
==>[e[7][1-knows->2],e[8][1-knows->4],e[9][1-created->3]]
==>[e[8][1-knows->4],e[10][4-created->5],e[10][4-created->5]]
gremlin> g.inject(arr).unfold().as('a','b').
......1>   math('a - b').
......2>     by(limit(local,1).values('weight')).
......3>     by(range(local,1,2).values('weight'))
==>-0.5
==>0.0
```

You could use `sack()` to avoid `math()` but I'm not sure it simplifies the picking apart of your inner list (i.e. your still stuck with `limit()`/`tail()`):

```
gremlin> arr = [[g.E(7).next(),g.E(8).next()],[g.E(8).next(),g.E(10).next()]]
==>[e[7][1-knows->2],e[8][1-knows->4]]
==>[e[8][1-knows->4],e[10][4-created->5]]
gremlin> g.withSack(0).inject(arr).unfold().
......1>   sack(assign).by(limit(local,1).values('weight')).
......2>   sack(minus).by(tail(local,1).values('weight')).
......3>   sack()
==>-0.5
==>0.0
```

Good question by the way.

Comment: Awesome approaches. Up until this point I had never even thought using `as()` with two strings within. While we are on the topic, is there a way to pick apart an array after `index()`? Like indexing with the map option, and selecting eg. index 2?

Comment: any list/array can be flattened to stream with `unfold()` or split with `local` scope using `range()` oriented steps. if that isn't clear or if if i've misunderstood, perhaps open up a new question and i can try to answer more fully

Comment: It's quite clear now. When I made that response, I was thinking of picking apart a map. But now I'm thinking clearer, and there's not only no need for a map, but a map could also be flattened back into its values with `select(values)`. You are correct. Thanks again.